# How do I pause a specific function without pausing the entire window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently using window.after(ms) to create a timer, but it just pauses the entire window. My timer does not need to count down, it just needs to pause the function for a few minutes. I have tried this:

```
def setTimer(mins=25):
    timer.config(text="In Progress")
    window.after(mins*60*1000)
    timer.config(text="Timer done!")
```

But it freezes the entire window. Is there a way to achieve this without doing so?

If the question isn't clear, please leave a comment and I will do my best to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make after() target a different function and leave tkinter to do the scheduling:

```py
def timerDone():
    timer.config(text="Timer done!")

def setTimer(mins=25):
    timer.config(text="In Progress")
    window.after(mins*60*1000, timerDone)
```